# Separate factor into columns R

Tags: r, tidyverse

I am trying to `separate` (tidyr) `line_text` into separate words so it's one word per column.

Data:

```
structure(list(ID = c(140L, 233L, 233L), 
pdf_name = structure(c(1L, 
2L, 2L), .
Label = c("GBD2016_2_1255_Venezuela_MoH_Epi_2012_9.pdf", 
"GBD2016_2_1351_Venezuela_MoH_Epi_2014_44.pdf"), 
class = "factor"), 
keyword = c("SEGÚN GRUPOS", "SEGÚN GRUPOS", "SEGÚN GRUPOS"
), line_text = list("2000 Gráfico 2 . CASOS DE MALARIA SEGÚN GRUPOS DE EDAD Y SEXO,                                                                                                                         EPIDEMIOLÓGICA 9 Año 2012", 
    "GRÁFICO 2. CASOS DE MALARIA SEGÚN GRUPOS DE EDAD Y SEXO, HASTA", 
    "GRÁFICO 2. CASOS DE            SEGÚN GRUPOS"), 
.Names = c("ID", "pdf_name", "keyword", 
"page_num", "line_num", "line_text", "token_text"), row.names = c(NA, 
-3L), class = "data.frame")
```

Coded used:

```
numcols<- make.unique(c(rep("word",10, sep  = " ")) )

df<- reportdiagn%>%
 (separate(reportdiagn$line_text,
        into = numcols, 
        sep = ("")))
```

I get the following error and can't work out how to fix it.

```
`Error in UseMethod("separate_") : 
 no applicable method for 'separate_' applied to an object of class "factor
```

Comment: Try: `separate(reportdiagn, "line_text", into = numcols, sep = " ")`

Comment: By the way, your example data *dput* is malformed, could you edit your post: `dput(head(reportdiagn, 3))`

Answer (score 0):

The data you pasted isn't quite right. Might be good to try that again - but I have tried to reproduce your data anyway. It might not be exactly the same. I have set linetext to be a character string - but I think the code below works in either character or factor.

In `select()`, you don't need to reference the data frame - the `%>%` already does that, you just need the name of the variable without quotes. Also, your `sep` needs to be a space or `\\b` for a word boundary.

```
ID <- c(140, 233, 233)
pdf_name <- factor(c(1, 2, 2),
    labels = c(
        "GBD2016_2_1255_Venezuela_MoH_Epi_2012_9.pdf", 
        "GBD2016_2_1351_Venezuela_MoH_Epi_2014_44.pdf") 
)
keyword <- c("SEGÚN GRUPOS", "SEGÚN GRUPOS", "SEGÚN GRUPOS")
line_text <- c("2000 Gráfico 2 . CASOS DE MALARIA SEGÚN GRUPOS DE EDAD Y SEXO, EPIDEMIOLÓGICA 9 Año 2012", 
               "GRÁFICO 2. CASOS DE MALARIA SEGÚN GRUPOS DE EDAD Y SEXO, HASTA", 
               "GRÁFICO 2. CASOS DE SEGÚN GRUPOS.")
reportdiagn <- data.frame(ID, pdf_name, keyword, line_text)

numcols<- make.unique(c(rep("word",10 )) )

df <- reportdiagn %>%
    separate(line_text,
              into = numcols, 
              sep = " ")
```

This produces some `NA` values where there's less than 10 words and truncates when there's more. I assume you're expecting that.

Comment: This was just a rough example so this doesn't matter.